# Select Long type variable in Querydsl

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

When i try to run this query :

```
Long count = ...;
List<CritereItem> items= new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(foo)
                     .list( new QCritereItem( foo.id, foo.name, count  ));
```

I got compilation error because the constructor expect `NumberPath<Long>` not `Long` at the variable `count` , So how to select a variable in querydsl ?

I replace count in constructor by :

```
Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class, count.toString())
```

But i got this execption

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@14edf4
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `CritereItem`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a constant through the QueryDSL constructor.

Check the Expressions static class for more informations:
[QueryDSL API Reference](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.2/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/Expressions.html)

```
NumberExpression<Long> count = Expressions.asNumber(...);
List<CritereItem> items = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(foo)
                          .list( new QCritereItem( foo.id, foo.name, count ));
```

Also note that if you want to aggregate a count, you can do it with `foo.count()`

Comment: the funtion `asNumber()` is undefined for the type `Expressions`

Comment: which version of QueryDSL are you using? Try to update to the lastest version.

Comment: i use 3.4.1 version

Comment: For 3.4.1, Try `Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class, ...)` . The second parameter has to be a String, to you may have to cast it with `Long.toString(...)`

Comment: I got this exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@14edf4`

Comment: Can't you upgrade QueryDSL to the lastest version? It will make a lots of things a lot simplier. Otherwise give the whole Exception and also the constructor for CritereItem.